# Control flow for returning list values

Tags: r, function, if-statement, control-flow

I'm trying to return a list of values given this function:

```
Pass_or_fail <- function(y){
 x = round(runif(y, 0, 100), 1)
  if(x>50){
    list(print("Passed"))
  }else if(x < 50){
    list(print("Failed"))
  }
}
```

When I pass a value into `y` for example `20` this should return a list of either `Passed` or `Failed` characters. However, the function above only returns a single vector. I wish for it to return 20 values relative to the condition provided above, mainly in list format.

I was thinking of creating a variable likeso:

```
t_list <- list(1:20)
#then
Map(Pass_or_fail(20), t_list)
```

example output (though not accurate):

```
 "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed" "Passed" "Failed"
```

I cannot seem to figure it out yet.

Comment: We need `ifelse` not `if() else`. I think you mean a vector when you say "list".

Comment: I've tried it with this, and it seems to work when inputting the function above: ```replicate(10, Pass_or_fail(1))```, although I would prefer a cleaner output.

Comment: What should happen when `x == 50` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your question at face-value,

```
Pass_or_fail <- function(y){
    x = round(runif(y, 0, 100), 1)
    
    lapply(
        x,
        FUN = function(x){
            
            if(x>50){
                list(print("Passed"))
            }else if(x < 50){
                list(print("Failed"))
            }
            
        }
    )
    
}
```

**Note:** Without `lapply` in your defined function, it is not possible to evaluate all values in `x`, as the length is defined by `y`. By using `lapply`, you will evaluate all values in `x` against your defined conditions.

And then feeding it into `lapply`, gives the following;

```
results <- lapply(
    X = 1:10,
    FUN = Pass_or_fail
    )
```

This gives 1 `list` pr. `X`, each with the length of `x` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Applying `map`, the function you wrote takes as input a vector not a single element. Try this:

```r
Pass_or_fail2 <- function(y) {
  x <- round(runif(y, 0, 100), 1)
  condition <- ifelse(x > 50, "passed", "failed")
  print(condition)
}

map(Pass_or_fail2(10), 1)
```

If you want a vector as output comment `print` in function `Pass_or_fail2` and use:

```r
unlist(map(Pass_or_fail2(10), 1))
```